# Wrestling with substitution rules

Tags: replacement, rule

### Summary

I am struggling with substitution rules.

#### Example

Here are several cases which are problematic:

```
Clear[a,α];
{a + 2 b + 1, -a - b, 2 a + 2 b, a^2 + 2 a b + b^2} /. {a + b -> α}
```

Actual result:

```
{1 + a + 2 b, -a - b, 2 a + 2 b, a^2 + 2 a b + b^2}
```

Desired result:

```
{1 + α +  b, -α, 2 α, α^2}
```

### Question

Currently, the rule is permuted for every case, e.g.

```
2 a + 2 b -> 2α
```

Can the alpha substitution rule be generalized That, is there a single rule to handle all cases?

Comment: You mean: "One to rule them all"? ;)

Comment: Use `PolynomialReduce` to obtain algebraic "substitutions". `In[208]:= 
PolynomialReduce[{a + 2 b + 1, -a - b, 2 a + 2 b, a^2 + 2 a b + b^2}, 
  a + b - alpha, {a, b}][[All, 2]]

Out[208]= {1 + alpha + b, -alpha, 2 alpha, alpha^2}`

Comment: Generally, to apply a relationship broadly, write the corresponding rule such that the LHS of the rule is as simple as possible, e.g., solution posted by @HenrikSchumacher. Since rules are applied to the structure of the internal (FullForm) representation, this will result in the highest number of matches with the LHS.

Answer (score 6):

```
{a + 2 b + 1, -a - b, 2 a + 2 b, a^2 + 2 a b + b^2} /. {a -> α - b} // Simplify
```

> {1 + b + α, -α, 2 α, α^2}

Answer (score 5):

Also

```
Simplify[{a + 2 b + 1, -a - b, 2 a + 2 b,  a^2 + 2 a b + b^2}, {a + b == α}]
```

> {1 + b + α, -α, 2 α, α^2}